# SSAS - adding new fields to fact table without errors

Tags: ssas

gurus!

I've inherited an SSAS 2014 multidimensional cube at work.  I've been doing SQL Server database work (queries, tables, stored procs, etc) for many years now.  But I'm a complete SSAS newbie.  And, even in my ignorance, I can tell that this cube I've inherited is a mess!

I've been able to keep the thing updated with new data each month, but now our company has rolled out a new product and I'm having to add five new fields to the fact table / view for keys related to that product, along with the related dimension views.  I've taken a couple of shots at it, but wind up hitting numerous errors when I process the fact table partitions.

BTW, heading off the natural question, there's no way I can roll the "five new fields" data into fields that already exist unless I completely rebuild the cube from scratch, which is out of the question right now.

So, I'll try to boil down what I THINK is the problem here.  Hoping someone can answer my question.

The fact data is located in four different data warehouse databases (names changed to protect company data) -

1. DB_Current
2. DB_2018
3. DB_2017
4. DB_2016

There is a fact view within each of those databases to stage the fact data.  That view is called "vw_fact" and is identical across all databases.  When that view gets pulled into the cube, it gets partitioned into four different partitions (per month-year) due to data size.

The new product was just rolled out this year, so I added the five new fields to "vw_fact" only in "DB_Current".  I didn't change the prior years' views in their respective databases.  My shot-in-the-dark guess there was that the prior years views would automically join the matching field names to the current year's view without needing the new fields.

When I tried processing the four years' worth of partitions, I then ran into numerous "field doesn't exist errors".

So, my questions are these:

1. Do I have to add five new fields to ALL FOUR views?  That is, the individual views within all four years' of databases?
2. If I have to do #1 above, do I then need to run a "Process Full" on all partitions for all four years?  Or do I need to run one of the other process options?

Thank you so much in advance for any advice you can offer here!

Joel

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the matching result sets for all partitions source queries. Though, that doesn't mean you will necessarily have to add it to all views. You can edit the source query for the different partitions in visual studio. If you for some reason don't want to edit the 4 views ( which I would probably do ) you could hard code the surrogate key for the unknown member or something similar in the queries of the partitions where the new fields are not relevant (if it's dimension foreign keys we're talking about, alternatively to 0 or something if it's measures). If you have new dimensions I would go for a FULL process.